# Django Replace with space from underscore in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my database *jobs* table, state field having values "New_Mexico". But I need to display in html page like *"New Mexico"*. Give some ideas for find and replace.

*views.py*

```
def result(request,user_id):
    userid=user_id
    query = Q(emp__companyname=userid) | Q(state=userid )
    details=jobs.objects.filter(query).select_related()
    return render_to_response('result.html', {'details': details})
```

*result.html*

```
{% for d in details %}
    <label>{{ d.state }}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7):

If this should be the default output when using `{{ object }}`, then you should override the `__unicode__` method of your model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(...)  # this field may hold our string "New_Mexico"
  ...
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title.replace('_', ' ')
```

A different approach might be using `{{ object.human_readable_title }}`, where you define a method in your model:

```
  def human_readable_title(self):
    return self.title.replace('_', ' ')
```

I see no reason to build your own template tag for this use case, except you want to use it for many fields of different models.

EDIT:
It seems you have a field called "state"  in your "jobs" class. So in your case, a solution might be:
in your model class create a method

```
def human_readable_state(self):
  return self.state.replace('_', ' ')
```

and in the template use:

```
<label>{{ d.human_readable_state }}</label>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Now i add my views and templates for user ref. Previous one not working properly..

Comment: +1 for `{{ object.human_readable_title }}`, Model class methods are the best option for formatted template outputs and django admin views.

Answer (score 4):

If your text is "python program language"

After use this code in your html in django
{{ data.value.split|join:"-" }}

Answer is : python-program-language

Comment: In my case, I need just to use `{{ data.split|join:"_" }}` (so omit `value`) as my data was already a string.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in template tag or filter to do this.

Write your own template filter.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters explains what you want.

Comment: Now i add my views and templates for user ref. Share your ideas